# Multi Step Form with Progress Bar using jQuery and CSS3 doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have taken the code from codepen. The muti step form works perfectly there. I have saved the code both in a single HTML file and in separate HTML, CSS and JS files. I have used both and neither go past the first DIV.
Here is the single file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>

</head>

<style>

/*custom font
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);*/

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
height: 100%;
/*Image only BG fallback*/

/*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
background:
    linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body  {
font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
width: 400px;
margin: 50px auto;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
background: white;
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
padding: 20px 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 10%;

/*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: montserrat;
color: #2C3E50;
font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
width: 100px;
background: #27AE60;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 10px 5px;
margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
font-size: 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #2C3E50;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 13px;
color: #666;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
margin-bottom: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
/*CSS counters to number the steps*/
counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
list-style-type: none;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 9px;
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
content: counter(step);
counter-increment: step;
width: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
display: block;
font-size: 10px;
color: #333;
background: white;
border-radius: 3px;
margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
content: '';
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
background: white;
position: absolute;
left: -50%;
top: 9px;
z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
/*connector not needed before the first step*/
content: none;
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
background: #27AE60;
color: white;
```

}

```
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
<!-- progressbar -->
<ul id="progressbar">
<li class="active">Account Setup</li>
<li>Social Profiles</li>
<li>Personal Details</li>
</ul>
<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
<input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
<input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
<input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
<textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button"    value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs   /jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show();
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
    'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
    'position': 'absolute'
  });
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

//de-activate current step on progressbar
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

//show the previous fieldset
previous_fs.show();
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
        scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
        left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({'left': left});
        previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity':     opacity});
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});

$(".submit").click(function(){  return false;})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Are there any suggestions as to why this would not work locally?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you put the code in files yourself (i.e. manual copy/paste)? Or did you use the CodePen "export" button?

Comment: I copied and pasted, I worked out today what the issue was. The jQuery used in this form requires extended jQuery.UI to work porperly. So I no I had to put in a request to load.
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

Comment: Would be interesting to know if it would work "out-of-the-box" if you used the CodePen "export" option instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied and pasted, I worked out today what the issue was. The jQuery used in this form requires extended jQuery.UI to work porperly. So I no I had to put in a request to load.